# How to use multiple email profile in SQL Server agent jobs?

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

The SQL Server alert system configuration page (see below image) allows me to choose only a single mail profile. Does that mean I can only use a single email address to send notifications in my SQL Server agent jobs? Basically I want to send out email using different email address, so that in the email client, like Outlook, I can filter and manage emails based on different sender email address. Is this possible?

[image]